# Openweather API, time always in my local time zone

Tags: javascript

I am including data from Openweather API which returns this, among other things:

```
dt: 1583876444
sys:
   country: "ES"
   sunrise: 1583822046
   sunset: 1583864165
timezone: 3600
```

My solution for timezone was to divide this number with 3600:

```
`Timezone: GMT ${data.timezone / 3600}:00 `
```

This somehow works and I get for example 'Timezone: GMT 9:00' although for some places like Tehran I get 'Timezone: GMT 3.5:00' and it is not ideal obviously. 
Any better solution for this?

For sunrise/sunset, I did this:

```
let date = new Date(data.sys.sunrise * 1000).toString();
  let sunrise = date.slice(16, 24);
...
`<h1>${sunrise}</h1>`
```

And I get what I want, like 03:50:36

Problem is it is always my local time, it shows me when sunrises in Tokyo but in my local time and not in Tokyo's local time. Obviously I would like to get Tokyo's local time. Is this doable?

Answer (score 6):

I faced the exact same problem with openweather. Add the timezone to the time and then times by 1000.

for sunrise/sunset:

```
const sunrise = new Date((data.sys.sunrise + data.timezone) * 1000)
```

You will get the local time

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend you to use Moment: https://momentjs.com/timezone/ is a solid library and user tested.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I tried but it is not what I need, at least I can't find it :(